# KeyError When Running Custom Search JSON API

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-custom-search

I am using the Custom Search JSON API on Python. I am running this code to test it out:

```py
import sys
print(sys.version)

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pprint
my_api_key = "(my censored api key)"
my_cse_id = "(my censored search engine id)"


def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']


results = google_search(
    'stackoverflow site:en.wikipedia.org', my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=10)
for result in results:
    pprint.pprint(result)
```

However, I am getting a KeyError for 'items'.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/first.py", line 17, in <module>
    'stackoverflow site:en.wikipedia.org', my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=10)
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/first.py", line 13, in google_search
    return res['items']
KeyError: 'items'
```

How do I fix the error?

Comment: Try `print(res)` right before you access `res['items']` so you can see the structure of `res`

Comment: Thanks. Just realized that my search engine was limited to only two sites so the query had no results.